# How do I drop packets that contain a certain ASCII string on Windows?

Tags: windows, firewall

I'm trying to find a way to block any packets that have particular character strings. I want to specify both the content to filter for and the destination port.  I've looked at several firewalls but none of them allow me to filter for the content of the packet, only the headers. This is for a Windows 7 system.

Comment: Bear in mind that a string can be split into two separated packets if it's a TCP connection. So it isn't just about filtering packets. The only tool I know is able to do this is Snort which @jmq mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Snort](http://www.snort.org/start/download).

> SNORT® is an open source network intrusion prevention system capable
>   of performing real-time traffic analysis and packet logging on IP
>   networks. Snort can perform protocol analysis, content
>   searching/matching and can be used to detect a variety of attacks and
>   probes, such as buffer overflows, stealth port scans, CGI attacks, SMB
>   probes, OS fingerprinting attempts, and much more. Snort is comprised
>   of two major components: (i) a detection engine that utilizes a
>   modular plug-in architecture (the “Snort Engine”) and (ii) a flexible
>   rule language to describe traffic to be collected (the “Snort Rules”).

You would create custom rules in the configuration:

> The rule header contains the information that defines the who, where,
>   and what of a packet, as well as what to do in the event that a packet
>   with all the attributes indicated in the rule should show up. The
>   first item in a rule is the rule action. The rule action tells Snort
>   what to do when it finds a packet that matches the rule criteria.
>   There are 5 available default actions in Snort, alert, log, pass,
>   activate, and dynamic. In addition, if you are running Snort in inline
>   mode, you have additional options which include drop, reject, and
>   sdrop.
>
> 1. alert - generate an alert using the selected alert method, and then log the packet
> 2. log - log the packet
> 3. pass - ignore the packet
> 4. activate - alert and then turn on another dynamic rule
> 5. dynamic - remain idle until activated by an activate rule , then act as a log rule
> 6. drop - block and log the packet
> 7. reject - block the packet, log it, and then send a TCP reset if the protocol is TCP or an ICMP port unreachable message if the protocol is UDP.
> 8. sdrop - block the packet but do not log it.

http://manual.snort.org/node29.html

It has a Windows version on the downloads page.

Answer (score 0):

Bitdefender internet security or total security has a feature in the privacy section which allows you to define a string considered your personal info or whatever you would wanna block. It will block that string to be sent or received so it will be blocked in both directions..sorry for my english